# How to extract all numeric like values from string?

Tags: python, regex, number-formatting

I have a strings that contain different values (numeric and non-numeric mixed). I want to be able to extract the values from the text. I could not get my head around how to extract all (or most of) possible cases. I have a partially working solution like this,

```
def extract_values(sentence):
    #sentence = normalizeString(sentence)
    matches = re.findall(r'((\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?)(?:\s+and\s+(\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?))?)', sentence)    
    # (\d\sto\s\d\s(and\s\d\/\d)*) << for adding 9 to 11, couldn't fix

    result = []
    for x,y,z in matches:
        if '/' in x:
            result.append(x)
        else:
            result.extend(filter(lambda x: x!="", [y,z]))
    return result
```

Driver code,

```
extract_values("He is 1 and 1/2 years old. He is .5 years old and he is 5 years old. He is between 9 to 11 or 9 to 9 and 1/2. He was born 11/12/20")
```

Incorrect answer:

```
['1 and 1/2', '5', '5', '9', '11', '9', '9 and 1/2', '11/12', '20']
```

Expected answer:

```
['1 and 1/2', '.5', '5', '9 to 11', '9 to 9 and 1/2', '11/12/20']
```

Please note the difference between 5 and .5, and 'x to y' and 'x to y and z'

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Tried changing `and` to `(and|to)`?

Comment: Do you really need to check Group 1 value for `/` char? Have a look at the solution below, please provide feedback. Please add pattern requirements/matching logic to the question.

Comment: You can catch the `.5` with @Daweo's answer by some little enhancement eg [like this](https://regex101.com/r/3A12bF/1).

Comment: Taking into account your previous question, I believe you need https://ideone.com/VG2qKH. Or do you need a different solution now?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import re
text = "He is 1 and 1/2 years old. He is .5 years old and he is 5 years old. He is between 9 to 11 or 9 to 9 and 1/2. He was born 11/12/20"
values = re.findall(r"\d+(?:\s?(?:and|/|to)\s?\d+)*",text)
print(values)
```

output

```
['1 and 1/2', '5', '5', '9 to 11', '9 to 9 and 1/2', '11/12/20']
```

Explanation: I used non-capturing group here. This pattern is searching for 1 or more digits followed by (`and` or `/` or `to`, possibly with leading and/or trailing whitespace, followed by 1 or more digits) repeated zero or more times.

If you wish to include leading `.` then you might prepend `\.?` to my pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks promising. The problem I can see is, .5 (or 0.5) is not captured in this. Any idea?

Comment: @Droid-Bird regarding *leading* dot like in `.5` you might preprend optional `\.` (literal dot) to my pattern so it become `r"\.?\d+(?:\s?(?:and|/|to)\s?\d+)*"` and output is then `['1 and 1/2', '.5', '5', '9 to 11', '9 to 9 and 1/2', '11/12/20']`

Comment: I inadvertently downvoted. Please make a tiny edit so I can correct my mistake (and leave a message informing me that you've done so).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re

def extract_values(sentence):
   num = r'\d*\.?\d+(?:/\d*\.?\d+)*'
   return re.findall(fr'{num}(?:\s+(?:and|to)\s+{num})*', sentence)

print(extract_values("He is 1 and 1/2 years old. He is .5 years old and he is 5 years old. He is between 9 to 11 or 9 to 9 and 1/2. He was born 11/12/20"))
# => ['1 and 1/2', '.5', '5', '9 to 11', '9 to 9 and 1/2', '11/12/20']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/P7EjVx), and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BVS8Z4/1).

**Details**:

- `\d*\.?\d+(?:/\d*\.?\d+)*` - a float/int number, and then zero or more occurrences of `/` and a float/int number
- `(?:\s+(?:and|to)\s+\d*\.?\d+(?:/\d*\.?\d+)*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s+(?:and|to)\s+` - `and` or `to` enclosed with one or more whitespaces
  - `\d*\.?\d+(?:/\d*\.?\d+)*` - a float/int number, and then zero or more occurrences of `/` and a float/int number.
  - 